# Using Regex to find second group of numbers in a mixed line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract just the 46,789,955.22 after the first group of letters, including .,- in the following line

```
123,145  ASD  25,678,345.22         46,789,955.22 USD 5,445,453.22
```

I have used this to extract:

```
(?<=[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])\s*[\d\.\,\-]*\s*([\d\.\,\-]*)
```

But this returns the first group of numbers after ASD as well.  Is there a way to only return a match if the number is preceded by a group of three letters, and somewhere in the rest of the line another group of three letters occurs?

Any time I try and use another lookahead to find the next group of letters I lose the capture group.

Comment: It's a tab (or white-space) separated line where all fields are in a specific place. Don't use a regex. Split the line and choose the good field.

Comment: I'd use `\b[A-Z]{3}\s*(\S+).*` to just get the first occurrence. If you precise the environment,  there may be better ways to achieve your goal splitting with whitespace being the most readable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead to assert that another country code appears somewhere after your target:

```
[A-Z]{3}\s*([\d.,-]*)(?=.*[A-Z]{3})
```

I also removed some unnecessary characters in your regex:

- If you're using group one, no need for the look behind at the front - just consume the code
- `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]` be be abbreviated to `[A-Z]{3}`
- Most characters don't need escaping within a character class, certainly none of yours (although the dash must be first or last to be a literal dash)